# Android How Get Option Menu ItemId, that add "menu" Dynamacally ? Explain Below

Tags: java, android, optionmenu

There is Some complexity ......How Can I Resolve

I Add the Option Menu Dynamacally

```
@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        menu.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < SplashActivity.arraylistsSports.size(); i++) {
            lists.add(SplashActivity.arraylistsSports.get(i));
            arryList.add(SplashActivity.arraylistsSportsURL.get(i));
            menu.add(i, i, i, SplashActivity.arraylistsSports.get(i));
            // menu.add(groupId, itemId, order, title)
        }

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

How can get `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` ItemId

Mean Get Id on "ItemSelected" and Perform Operation

Basically I add or I parse data form XML and Save required data `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`

I want to Open URL `arryList.add(SplashActivity.arraylistsSportsURL.get(i));`that added in "arrayList" -------------------------------------------------

```
![Perfoem Operation On Option Menu ItemId Click "ItemId in Order loke Idexes" :)]
```

[image]

```
 onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

How we Can get Id

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

    //  case R.id.menu_settings:

    //  break;

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Artical is useful for me .... check the following URL (link)

> http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/android-creating-option-menu-programmatically/

In My Case if I chage the XML Items, mean Length greater than Current Items

Then Update the Apk version with Respectable XML Iten Lenth equal to ArrayList lenght equal.

Or Chek the Maximum cases

```
   case MENU_ITEM1:


            break;
```

mean grater than your Possiblities :)

If you have any Idia plz Share ... :-)

Edited Ans:

In my Case i Add

```
 menu.add(i, i, i, SplashActivity.arraylistsSports.get(i));
            // menu.add(groupId, itemId, order, title)
```

itemId in For Loop mean i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 .... and So On

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

case 0:
            URL = SplashActivity.arraylistsSportsURL.get(0);
            GetLiveTvToken();
            break;

        case 1:
            URL = SplashActivity.arraylistsSportsURL.get(1);
            GetLiveTvToken();
            break;

        case 2:
            URL = SplashActivity.arraylistsSportsURL.get(2);
            GetLiveTvToken();
            break;

        case 3:
            URL = SplashActivity.arraylistsSportsURL.get(3);
            GetLiveTvToken();
            break;
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
    and So On till 500 Items :-)
}
}
```